# How to download RSS feed which checks for javascript support

Tags: javascript, c#, xml, cookies, rss

I want to download using C# and HttpWebRequest this RSS feed: http://www.alarabiya.net/.mrss/ar/arab-and-world.xml

But when my program does the HTTP request, it gets an HTML document saying "This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled":

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name) { // Local function for getting a cookie value
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start!=-1) {
        c_start=c_start + c_name.length + 1;
        c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);

        if (c_end==-1) 
            c_end = document.cookie.length;

        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) { // Local function for setting a value of a cookie
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString()) + ";path=/";
}
function getHostUri() {
    var loc = document.location;
    return loc.toString();
}
setCookie('YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666', '78.245.108.141', 10);
try {  
    location.reload(true);  
} catch (err1) {  
    try {  
        location.reload();  
    } catch (err2) {  
        location.href = getHostUri();  
    }  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Using Fiddler, I see that the xml file is retrieved when a cookie is sent:

```
GET http://www.alarabiya.net/.mrss/ar/arab-and-world.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: www.alarabiya.net
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://www.alarabiya.net/.mrss/ar/arab-and-world.xml
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666=78.245.108.141
```

So, do I have to send this cookie by hard-coding it, or is there an automatic way to do that?
(or maybe there is another way to bypass the javascript check?)